# How to make inner shadow in bottom navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: adding inner shadow for bottom navigation bar]

I was trying to make it myself by new container and make it all from scratch but I am for something already handled in flutter so if anyone has a library making that or something native in flutter making the inner shadow I would be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by, also adjusting the elevation level of the shadow:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Inner Shadow Bottom Navigation Bar'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
        items: [
          TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.search, title: 'Search'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.person, title: 'Profile'),
        ],
        initialActiveIndex: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        style: TabStyle.react,
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        elevation: 8,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```